# Python JSON parsing: ignore sub-objects

Tags: python, json, parsing

I only want to parse the root object of a JSON string. If this object contains any key where the value is also an object, the value should be kept as string, and should not be treated as Python dictionary.

```
input = '{ "a": 1, "b": { "c": 2 } }'
```

Needed outcome:

```
result = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': '{ "c": 2 }'
}
```

The reason for doing so is because the sub-objects are large, and we won't process them here, so parsing and storing them as typed values are not useful. Surely some parsing have to be done, but at least objects are not created, the deep processing of the token can be skipped.

After using `json.loads(input)`, I would be able to convert back the value via `json.dumps(result['c'])`. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe a pre-created `JSONDecoder` which yields all sub-object tokens as string?

Comment: how do you want to handle arrays in this case?

Comment: @rv.kvetch I don't work with arrays now. I know that the values are primitives or objects only.

Answer (score 0):

Definetely not the best solution and maybe something you have thought of already but here is a solution which converts all values which are `dicts` to `strings` after the fact.

```py
input = '{ "a": 1, "b": { "c": 2 } }'

import json

data = json.loads(input)

for k, v in data.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        data[k] = str(v)
```